# Probability and continuous distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, covariance

Suppose that the daily consumption of pepsi in ounces is normally distributed with normal(13, 4) in ounces. The daily amount consumed is independent of other days except adjacent days where the covariance is -1. If the student has two six packs of 16 ounce pepsi bottles, what is the probability that some pepsi remaims at the end if the two weeks?

Can someone explain to me how to approach this question?

Comment: Assuming that the student never throws away any cola: Try recentering the data.  Since $13 \cdot 14 = 182$ and $12 \cdot 16 = 192$, consider a series of random variables $X_i \sim {\cal N}(0, 4), 1 \leq i \leq 14$, with $\sigma(X_i, X_{i+1}) = -1$.  Then $E(X_iX_{i+1}) = -1$.  How would you determine the probability that $\sum X_i < 10$?

Comment: Also keep in mind that $\sigma^2(X+Y) = \sigma^2(X)+2\sigma(X, Y)+\sigma^2(Y)$.

Comment: What is 10 from?

Comment: $10 = 192-182$. Notionally, the student starts out with enough for $14$ days of $13$ ounces each, with $10$ ounces left over. The question becomes, to what extent does the variance contribute to using up those $10$ ounces?